# Iterate from "0" to "ZZZZZ"

Tags: javascript, optimization, algorithm

I was given an assignment, it was as follows:

Give a JS code snippet which writes to the console from:
"0" to "ZZZZZ" all the combination of the characters of a-z, 0-9 and A-Z.

Is my solution correct?
I am sure there are better ways to achieve the same, can anybody show some? 
My code is:

```
function createCharSet(){
    var charset = "", c;

    for(c=48;c<58;c++){
        charset += String.fromCharCode(c);
    }
    for(c=97;c<123;c++){
        charset += String.fromCharCode(c);
    }   
    for(c=65;c<91;c++){
        charset += String.fromCharCode(c);
    }

    return charset;

}


function getNext(curr, charSet){
    var 
        length = curr.length,
        arr = curr.split(""),
        radix = charSet.length,
        i, c;

    for(i=length-1;i>-1;i--){
        c = charSet.indexOf(arr[i])+1;

        if(c==radix){
            arr[i]=charSet[0];
            if(i==0)
                return;
        }else{
            arr[i]=charSet[c];
            break;
        }
    }

    return arr.join("");
}

function iterate() {
    var 
        charSet = createCharSet(),
        maxLen = 4,
        len,
        i,
        arr,
        curr;

    for(len = 1;len<maxLen+1;len++){
        arr = [];
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            arr.push(charSet[0]);
        }

        curr = arr.join("");
        while(curr) {
            console.log(curr);
            curr = getNext(curr, charSet);
        };
    }

}

iterate();
```

Comment: Any reason why the title of your question is so different from the actual task you were given?

Comment: Reason: slept only a few hours. 
Edited the title... was it really so different?

Comment: Yes and no. The logic's the same, but the previous title implied that `a` was the lowest value in the charset, and `9` was the highest, but the code said otherwise. Also, an order of magnitude difference between the end values, which is something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minor observations:

1. I'd just hardcode the `charset` in this case. Doing so is faster to write (and a lot more explicit) than building it with a bunch of loops.
2. The modulo operator `%` is a good friend to have for this, as it'll let you "wrap around" array indices.

Overall, there's too much code here, I think. This is just counting in base 62.

It'd be awesome if `Number.prototype.toString()` accepted 62 as an argument, but, unfortunately, it only seems to accept bases 2-36. Similarly, it'd be great if we could somehow use the built-in base64 encoding function (`btoa`), but it's, well, base *64* (and it's got other issues). So we do have to roll our own.

Now, if this was base 10, we could obviously just do

```
var limit = Math.pow(10, 5); // i.e. 100000

for(var i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

which will print 0-99999.

Using this same basic setup, we can print our base62 values. Our `limit` will be \$base^{numberOfDigits}\$ just like \$10^5\$ will end up printing five 9s. So for 0-ZZZZZ we'll need to loop from zero to `Math.pow(62, 5)`.

And of course, we'll have to do the actual base62 conversion. The basic algorithm is:

1. Get the char corresponding to \$value\bmod base\$ (e.g. `charset[538 % 62] => charset[42]`) and add it to the output string.
2. Set \$value\$ to the quotient of \$\frac{value}{base}\$ (e.g. `Math.floor(538 / 62) => 8`).
3. If value is bigger than zero, go to step 1. Otherwise, return the output.

In code:

```
var output = "";
do {
  output = charset[value % base] + output;
  value = (value / base) | 0; // bitwise floor trick
} while(value > 0);
return output;
```

Putting it all together, I get this:

```
// define our base62 function (using an IIFE)
var toBase62 = (function () {
  var charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
      base = charset.length; // 62, natch

  return function (value) {
    // TODO: It'd be nice to guard against negative values here (see comments)
    var string = "";
    do {
      string = charset[value % base] + string;
      value = (value / base) | 0;
    } while(value > 0);
    return string;
  }
}());

// loop for a long, long time
for(var i = 0, l = Math.pow(62, 5) ; i < l ; i++) {
  console.log( toBase62(i) );
}
```

Note that it takes **forever** to print all the 916,132,832 values from 0 up to \$62^5\$. JS ain't *that* fast. I haven't explored optimization, so for testing, I'd advice using (much) fewer iterations.

Comment: To guard against negatives, you could swap out the do...while fo a while loop with the same condition and `return string || "0";` since primitive empty string is falsy.

Comment: @cbojar Won't work, I'm afraid. The string will actually be `"undefined"` - not an empty string - if the input is negative. So you would have to check for negative values before entering the loop.

Comment: No it would not, as changing the do...while to a while loop would implicitly check at the top and bypass the loop completely.

Comment: @cbojar Sorry, misread your first comment. You're right

Answer (score 2):

I would store the numeric value of each digit in an array, increment the array and then build a string, rather than trying to increment the string directly.

```
var charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    digits = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    max = charset.length - 1, 
    length = digits.length, 
    i = length, 
    output = '0';

while(true) {
    console.log(output);
    while (digits[--i] == max) digits[i] = 0;
    if (i < 0) break;
    digits[i]++;
    for (output = '', i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (output || digits[i]) output += charset[digits[i]];
    }
}
```

Instead of rebuilding the output string from scratch each time we can also use `substr` and replace only the parts that have changed.

```
var charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    digits = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    max = charset.length - 1, 
    end = digits.length - 1, 
    output = '0', 
    zeroes, i;

while(true) {
    console.log(output);
    for (i = end, zeroes = ''; digits[i] == max; i--) {
        digits[i] = 0;
        zeroes += '0';
    }
    if (i < 0) break;
    digits[i]++;
    output = output.substr(0, output.length - zeroes.length - 1) + charset[digits[i]] 
        + zeroes;
}
```

These will both still take an extremely long time.